# How to query WP Multisite primary site link

Tags: multisite

Currently I have created a multisite for my client. Within the network, there are a (primary)corporate site, a newsbites site and a blog site. Is there a way to query the primary site link, so that newsbites and blog site can connect back to the (primary) corporate site, without hard coding the site url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `network_home_url( $path = '', $scheme = null )`.
You can see it in `/wp-includes/link-template.php`.

Examples:

```
// Root of main site
$network_home = network_home_url();

// About page on main site
$network_about = network_home_url( 'about/' );
```

In a network, the main site has always the same ID as the network ID. `network_home_url()` uses `get_current_site()` which return the global variable (sigh) `$current_site`, an instance of `stdClass`. This one is filled in `wp-includes/ms-settings.php`, which in turn is loaded in `wp-settings.php` **before** mu-plugins are loaded.

So you can rely on it in your plugin or theme.

Comment: I tried.... It actually bring me back to the child homepage. Or perhaps I wrote it wrongly? Below how I type the code...

<a href="<?php network_home_url( $path = '', $scheme = null );?>" class="mainBrand"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) ?>/images/brand.svg" ></a>

Comment: Use `network_home_url()` without any parameters if you don’t want to change them.

Comment: Toscho, I afraid will hate me. No luck even I do it without parameters. Wordpress just direct me back to the current site home page. I actually wished to have the link call back to the main Primary site. Just like when you signup an acc with wp.com, ppl can click on wp icon to go back to wp.com site. not the main acc site.